# before_validation not modifing data after update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have the following code in a model that strips a phone number of all but the numbers.

```
before_validation :strip_phone_numbers

def strip_phone_numbers
  self.home_phone.gsub!(/[^0-9]/, '') if self.home_phone.present?
  self.work_phone.gsub!(/[^0-9]/, '') if self.work_phone.present?
  self.mobile_phone.gsub!(/[^0-9]/, '') if self.mobile_phone.present?
end
```

Now this works perfectly for the controller#create but for update it doesn't modify the data. Here is the update action:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = 'The user was successfully updated.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    end
  end
end
```

My inclination is to blame the update_attributes in that the before_validation is running on some other self. But i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call save, `ActiveRecord` will check if any attribute was changed. If there's no change it won't update the model.
Using `gsub!` you are only grabing the string and changing its value. This won't tell to `ActiveRecord` the attribute was changed so the model won't be updated.
`ActiveRecord` use the attributes setter to keep the changes in the model, so you need to use them:

```
def strip_phone_numbers
  self.home_phone = self.home_phone.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '') if self.home_phone.present?
  self.work_phone = self.work_phone.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '') if self.work_phone.present?
  self.mobile_phone = self.mobile_phone.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '') if self.mobile_phone.present?
end
```

Comment: Awesome, explain more "doesn't make the ActiveRecord dirty"

Comment: Updated @Greggawatt. I can improve it at home later, if you need